# Grid view Row_Command issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

my gridview Row command code looks like

```
protected void GridView_Admins_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView sourceGrid = sender as GridView;

        int currentIndex = 0;
        GridViewRow currentRow = null;

        if (string.Compare(e.CommandName, "SHOW", true) == 0)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument.ToString(), out currentIndex))
            {

                currentRow = sourceGrid.Rows[currentIndex];

                if (long.TryParse(sourceGrid.DataKeys[currentRow.RowIndex].Values["EmployeeID"].ToString(), out this.employeeId))
                    this.ShowAdministrativeRightsForUser();
            }
        }
    }
```

I also have paging enabled in gridview. When I want to edit record I click on particular cell and i can edit records. However when I am on second page when i click on a cell to edit record, I get error at row `currentRow = sourceGrid.Rows[currentIndex];` saying Index out of range.
What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the index :

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
```

Comment: No this does not work..I am still getting same error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"

Comment: How and what are you setting the CommandArgument to? Can you add the <asp:GridView> code you are using to your original question?